# How can I migrate asp.net website to a wordpress site?

Tags: migration

As I just know just the basics of html language and this site uses various technologies like html, jquery, bootstrap, css etc  how can I migrate this website to a wordpress site which I am pretty proficient with. The website is belhasacarrental.com

I know the site is not secure yet but I will renew it and I am into digital marketing so please help.

If it's not viable to migrate this dynamic website I guess I will have to learn these languages which I might not have time for.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You're not going to be able to just migrate it. You'd need to rebuild it in WordPress. You might be able to re-use stylesheets and JavaScript, but you'd need to rebuild your templates as WordPress templates in PHP, and use PHP to implement any additional functionality in WordPress. WordPress' developer documentation is available here: https://developer.wordpress.org/

Comment: @JacobPeattie okay I got it. Thank you for your help.